# Question on word combinations with exclusivity

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations, combinatorics-on-words

"How many 4 letter words on the alphabet {a,b,c} in which 'a' occurs *exactly* twice are there?"

My answer is incorrect as I answered 3*3*2*2 4 letter words.

However, this doesn't necessarily remove 'a' from the letter choices. What would be the correct way to solve this?

Comment: Can you explain why you chose $3$ for the first, $3$ for the second, $2$ for the third, and $2$ for the fourth terms in your product?  It is not clear.  It will help you to understand why your answer is wrong if we can explain why your choices were incorrect.

Comment: The order doesn't really matter but I thought going from 3 to 2 would reduce the option pool from a,b,c to b,c

Comment: It sounds as though your logic was to pick a letter from $\{a,b,c\}$ for the first character in your word, to pick again from $\{a,b,c\}$ for the second character, then to pick from only $\{b,c\}$ for both the third and fourth characters.  This is as you expected incorrect.  This answers the question of "How many 4-letter words are there where any $a$'s *if they occur at all* only occur within the first two characters of the word?" and counts arrangements like aabc, aacc, abcc, bcbc, and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of proceedng in order i.e. choosing first letter, then second etc. , choose which positions you want $a$ to occur in , and then choose what should come in the other positions.

For example, we have four positions $1,2,3,4$. Two of these positions can be chosen in $\binom 42 = 6$ ways. We place $a$ in these places.

Now, in the rest of the places, we have a choice of either $b$ or $c$ going in each place. Two places, two choices for each place gives a total of $2^2 = 4$ choices.

Multiplying these gives us $6 \times 4 = 24$ choices.

To actually write down all the words, pick each possible combination of two places, put $a$ there, and vary $b,c$ across the other places.

For example, fixing positions $2$ and $4$ for $a$ gives $baba,baca,caba,caca$, four of the desired words.

---

As for your answer, reducing the option pool cannot be done by position, since the positions of $a$ don't occur in order, or say within the first two positions, or in any particular pattern. However, treating them independently of the other positions does the job.

Comment: Great explanation! Question: How did you figure out that there were 6 ways to choose 2 of the positions? Did you use binomial theorem? If so, why is it 4 choose 2 instead of 3 choose 2? EDIT: Nevermind, I see you were choosing 2 out of the 4 positions not 2 out of the 3 letters.

Comment: Because we are choosing the *positions* in which to put $a$. The number of positions available is four, and the number in which $a$ is to appear is two. Hence, the answer in that case is $\binom 42$ (the formula for "number of ways of choosing $k$ things out of $n$" is $\binom nk$). Note that we are taking *combinations* of places, and not permutations, because if $a$ appears in both these places, swapping them would give the same word. Suppose we were choosing letters, the term $\binom 32$ would appear somewhere. But we are not, so it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Approach via multiplication principle.

$$\underline{~~~}~\underline{~~~}~\underline{~~~}~\underline{~~~}$$

- Step 1: Since we know that $a$ must occur exactly twice, let us pick which two positions within our word are occupied by $a$'s.  For example we might have chosen the second and third positions like below:

$$\underline{~~~}~\underline{~a~}~\underline{~a~}~\underline{~~~}$$

- Step 2: Pick what *non-a* letter appears in the furthest left unoccupied space.  For example we could have chosen $b$ like below:

$$\underline{~b~}~\underline{~a~}~\underline{~a~}~\underline{~~~}$$

- Step 3: Pick what *non-a* letter appears in the final remaining unoccupied space.  For example, we could again have chosen $b$ like below:

$$\underline{~b~}~\underline{~a~}~\underline{~a~}~\underline{~b~}$$

Multiply the number of options available to complete each step to get the final count.